# What is the most compact way in JavaScript to force a value in a range of values?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I have a simple 2 line procedure that's like

```
if ( bgwidth < 0 ) { bgwidth = 0; }
else if ( bgwidth > 100 ) { bgwidth = 100; }
```

and I'm wondering what is the most compact way to do it. Is there some way with bitshift operators? :)

Comment: File under: Nonsensical micro-optimization // For unreadability I’d use a nested `Math.min`/`.max`, makes for a nice one-liner. (Don’t forget to not comment the code in that case, ruins the fun.)

Answer (score 3):

`Math.min()` and `Math.max()` might do the trick:

```
Math.min(Math.max(0, bgwidth), 100);
```

And for readbility:

```
function fitBetween(value, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(min, value), max);
}
```